# Lightning App Custom Nav Tab Showing Recent List not Lightning Page

Tags: lightning-apps

My ignorance is going to be on full display here.

As I am learning I have developed a custom Lightning App called WidgetServices.

When I select WidgetServices I have 5 navigation tabs. 1 For dashboard, 1 for reports, 3 custom objects to track widget specific task.  EditWidget, CopyWidget, CreateWidget.

For the EditWidget custom object I have created a Lightning Record Page.

My desire which may be out of line....Is that AFTER loading the WidgetServices App I want to click on the EditWidget custom object tab and instead of seeing my Recently Viewed list I want to see my Lightning record page.

I have activated it as Org Default and reloaded the page but it still just displays the Recently Viewed List.

I think I'm doing something wrong because I can't see my Lightning Record page anywhere in the WidgetServices App.

Can I do what I want and I'm just missing something or is it not supported?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My desire which may be out of line....Is that AFTER loading the WidgetServices App I want to click on the EditWidget custom object tab and instead of seeing my Recently Viewed list I want to see my Lightning record page.

This is the expected behavior with what you have built so far. When you click on a Tab associated to an Object, you will always land on the landing page of that Object where you have the different List Views available, and Recently Viewed is the default.

Once you click on one of the records on the list view, you will be then navigated to the [Lightning Record Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_app_builder_customize_lex_pages.htm&type=5) that you have created with the all other details for that particular record.

If you need to customize the behavior for the `EditWidget` custom object tab, you will need to create a custom [App Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lightning_page_types.htm&type=5) instead. In that case, you will need to remove the tab of the object from the navigation items and expose your custom page. To learn more about building one, you can refer to [Build an App Home Lightning Page](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/lightning_app_builder/lightning_app_builder_apphome) trailhead.